How to remove html code from a string in PHP
I am a novice in PHP code. I am maintaining a legacy product which is written in PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Oct 30 2014 20:12:53).
The application has search options in various pages and if the user enters a search string like this
 '"><img src=x onerror=alert(1)> and hit search, the page is searching the DB for the matching entries and once the control comes back to the UI, a JAVASCRIPT alert is shown with Content as "1".

I searched online and found this link: CLICK HERE. I tried htmlentities, but it didn't work in my project.
when I apply htmlentities on the input string, It is converting it to '%\\'\\"><img src=x onerror=alert(1)>%'
Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks in advance.
Ashwin
TRIED this
I don't want the Javascript alert to appear.

Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php. Please add relevant code that is "not working" if you have an issue with that. Also be sure to encode both quote types, look at constants.

when I apply htmlentities on the input string, It is converting it to '%\\'\\"><img src=x onerror=alert(1)>%'...are you quite sure? Demo: https://3v4l.org/Clkj6 . Can you provide a [mre] for that result?
